# Why is this small section of my lawn brown?

Tags: lawn

[image: brown]

This is the access area to the septic.

HOWEVER, just two weeks ago this was green and overgrown. Tank was pumped out last year.

I live in New England, temp as been mostly average, watering 3 times/wk, seeded 1 week ago and have TruGreen regular service.

What could account for the dramatic change?

Comment: Have you lived in this house more than one year? The brown area looks suspiciously like an old septic tank, and was wondering if that could be the case.

Comment: @Jurp Yes, 7 years.  Tank was inspected.  Not ruling out septic issues, but a week ago it was green.

Comment: @Ecnerwal  There are no access ports showing in the photo. I don't know where you live, but in the northern US they are concrete pipes covered with a concrete cap. The top foot or so is above grade and they are not buried. Tank pumping is required when a house is sold, so the OP could easily have just moved into the house. Reading comprehension is not a problem for me. I explained WHY I thought it might be an old tank, not that it WAS an old tank.

Comment: I live in the Northern USA. **Only newer systems are built that way,** and there's no requirement to upgrade them until the whole system is replaced. The riser on modern systems may be concrete or plastic. On older systems, you dig until you find the tank, and dig to find the cover, possibly aided by diagrams and maps that may or may not be accurate. I tend to put an annual flowerbed there on older systems (which is every system but the one on the newest house, at houses I've lived in) because it's more reliable as a locator than most septic maps I've had to use. Most just put the sod back.

Comment: Did Tru-green apply fertilizer or other chemical burn recently? Have they done so in the past? If so, I'm wondering if there's some strange set of circumstances where an over application did NOT cause problems elsewhere because normal soil depth allowed an over-application of something to migrate away from the root zone everywhere, but shallow soil depth prevented it from leaving the pictured area. That said, my first thought was that a tarp or plywood had been left there - continued.

Comment: If the grass were actively growing under cooler, well watered conditions and then you had an unseasonably hot day (as we recently have) perhaps the thin layer of soil on the slab got hot enough to damage the roots. I can't really conceive of a scenario where something really hot raised the internal temp of the tank enough to cause the damage or some volatile chemical made its way in there and evaporated through the slab.

Comment: @Jurp, Ecnerwal, That Idiot:  Tank is old for sure.  lawn company applied first application a few weeks ago.  I seeded last week.  They are applying the next application next week.  We did have a 90+ day last Sunday and the soil is not deep in this spot so that could be a possibility.